# Overwrite a file?

Tags: files

I have a file named config.yml in a directory I need to be able to edit it and then overwrite it. When ever I would edit it and save it with the same name it would ask to overwrite and I would say yes but it had overwritten a config.yml in another place not the one I had wanted. I need help because I need to overwrite the right config file.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should `cd` into the directory before opening the file and make sure that it's saving the file to the right place

Comment: I am using nano I need to be able to do so in it.

Comment: @ebank36 Sorry, I don't quite get what you mean by that comment. Where is the file you are editing? Where did it save the file?

Comment: ok so I edited my file in /home/ebank36/minecraft/plugins/ChatManager/config.yml and i need to overwrite it in the exact same place, but when I try it saves it in /home/ebank36/minecraft

Comment: @ebank36 You should `cd /home/ebank36/minecraft/plugins/ChatManager/` then run `nano config.yml` and see if that works